# Merge on Dates column returning NaN

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, merge

I have 2 data frames I am trying to join on multiple conditions `[col1 , col2]`. `col2` is a date in this format 02/17/2018. Both data frames have the dates column in '%m/%d/%Y' format. I have I have tried to make sure they are the same format and have attempted to strip any white spaces. Both data comes from 2 CSV files.

```
df_next_date = pd.merge(df_calls, df_nums, how= 'left', left_on= 
['ticker','date'], right_on=['ticker','day_after'])

date       ticker     meas     meas2    meas3
10/27/2018 amazon     5        NaN      NaN
02/02/2017 amazon     3        NaN      NaN
05/20/2018 apple      2        NaN      NaN
```

I attempted to use strip to get rid of any white spaces with no luck.

```
df_nums['day_after'] = df_nums['day_after'].str.strip()
```

Here is a sample of the 2 date frames.

```
df_calls
date         ticker    meas
10/27/2018   amazon    5
02/02/2017   amazon    3
05/20/2018   apple     2


df_nums
date       ticker    meas2    meas3
10/27/2018 amazon      2        6
02/02/2017 amazon      5        4
05/20/2018 apple       7        5
```

The odd thing is I have another date column in `df_nums` that successfully joined to the date column of df_calls with no issue so I believe it must be with in the `df_nums['day_after']` column.I have looked tried the answers for similar issues her

Comment: Can you post samples of the initial DataFrames?

Comment: Could you provide (samples of) the relevant CSV files? Currently, the question is a bit hard to answer as it reads like "I'm doing something that ought to work but doesn't", which it's hard to do much about. One thing you might find helpful, though, would be to convert the string dates to `pd.Timestamp` through `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: I updated with samples. I did try this in order to align the types 
    df_nums['day_after'] = pd.to_datetime(df_nums['day_after'])

Comment: To help debug, instead of `how='left'`, do `how='outer'`, and add `indicator=True`.

Comment: I tried this just now and i see many rows do pull data but many just return NaN. But oddly when the meas2 and meas3 show up the date column turns to NaN

Comment: I see no `day_after` column in the samples you have provided. I see a `date` column in both `df_nums` and `df_calls`. So please include `day_after` in your sample, thanks.

Comment: Can you run the following for each DataFrame: `for foo in zip(df_calls.head()['date'], map(repr, df_calls.head()['date']): print(foo)`, and `for foo in zip(df_nums.head()['day_after'], map(repr, df_nums.head()['day_after']): print(foo)`

Comment: @PMende i am getting a invalid syntax because of the colon. Not really sure how to fix that

Comment: @DSM i tried the outer and indicator true. It seems to match some so half way down the measures = NaN but then the Measures show up but the data is then NaN